# Gas Calculation -- Can't find mistake

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

## This is my JavaScript-Code

it should calculate how much CO2 produces a person per km. it is a school subject an i am just at the beginning so please go easy on me...

#### also i just registered to stockoverflow

i am also a newbee here...i thank you in advance...

```
window.onload = function () {

    // CO2 Verbrauch = ((fs / ksv) * ta) / am)+(fs*0.14)
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn'); // Initiate Calulation

    var ta = document.getElementById('treibstoffart') // Selector
    var benzin = document.getElementById('benzin'); // Option 1
    var diesel = document.getElementById('diesel'); // Option 2
    var autogas = document.getElementById('autogas'); // Option 3

    var ksv = document.getElementById('Kraftstoffverbrauch'); // Inputfield
    var fs = document.getElementById('Fahrtstrecke'); // Inputfield
    var am = document.getElementById('Anzahl der Mitfahrer'); // Inputfield

    var ausgabe = document.getElementById('ergebnis'); // Result
```

### every option has a fixed number

```
    var tsa = function () { //////// NOT SURE WHAT IS WRONG
        if (benzin) {
            benzin.value = 2.33;
        } else if (diesel) {
            diesel.value = 2.64;
        } else if (autogas) {
            autogas.value = 1.64;
        }
    }; // End of function (treibstoffart)


    btn.onclick = function () {
        ausgabe.innerText = (((fs.value * 1 / ksv.value * 1) * tsa) / am.value * 1) + (fs.value * 0.14); //////// TSA is added here
    };

} // End of function (window.onload)
```

## This is the HTML Code

#### i am using Bootstrap as you can see but i think the most problem is the selector i use for the function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Übung 1 Rechner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="uebung_1.css">
    <script src="uebung_1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <section>
        <form class="form-inline">
            <select id="treibstoffart" class="form-control">
                <option value="" selected>... auswählen ...</option>
                <option value="benzin">Benzin</option>
                <option value="diesel">Diesel</option>
                <option value="autogas">Autogas</option>

                <input id="Kraftstoffverbrauch" type="text" placeholder="Kraftstoffverbrauch (Liter/100km)" value=""
                    class="form-control">
                <input id="Fahrtstrecke" type="text" placeholder="Fahrtstrecke (in km)" value="" class="form-control">
                <input id="Anzahl der Mitfahrer" type="text" placeholder="Anzahl der Mitfahrer" value=""
                    class="form-control">

                <button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-primary" value="">Berechnen</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" value="Reset">Clear</button>
        </form>
    </section>

    <section>
        <p>Das Ergebnis wird hier Angezeigt</p>
        <p id="ergebnis"></p>
        <p>Weitere Ergebnisse für Reisebus, Bahn, Flugzeug</p>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ain't `ta()` supposed to `return` anything?

Comment: *"it doesnt seen to work"* - Now is an opportune time to begin investigating your browser's debugging tools.  First, always look at the browser's development console.  If your code is generating an error, that's where it will be.  From there, take a look at the browser's script debugger.  You can place a breakpoint in the code to pause execution, and step through the code line by line as it executes to observe the runtime behavior and variable values.  When you do all these things, where/how specifically does the code fail?  What is the first thing to go wrong?

Comment: @ B. go

this is my HTML code...

Comment: @david -- i already read the error code in the brower -- but not getting smarter of that -- i am sorry -- i am a beginner and still learning

Comment: @Jan-MichaelWaiser: What "error code"?  If your browser is showing you an error message then it's very likely telling you what the problem is.  This is useful information to consult when trying to solve the problem.

Comment: @david Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at window.onload (uebung_1.js:27)
window.onload @ uebung_1.js:27
load (async)
(anonymous) @ uebung_1.js:1

Comment: @Jan-MichaelWaiser: The browser is telling you that `btn` is `null`.  So `document.getElementById('btn')` isn't finding the element you assume it is.  (Basically, the button you're looking for doesn't exist.)

Comment: but i did on my html the btn ...it it possible to send images or but the html code somewhere?...

<button class="btn btn-primary">Berechnen</button>

Comment: you want `document.getElementsByClassName` since `btn` isn't an id, its a class

Comment: You're also not returning anything from your ta() function. Should do something like `return 1 * 2.33` in each of your if/else if clauses.

Comment: @SuperStormer  -- wow...thank you i did not see that :)))

Comment: @Brant -- thank you for you comment -- i tried it and i receive now the NaN after i click the button

Comment: @Brant -- now i get a NaN after i press my button...

Comment: Please go read [ask] before you ask the next question here. The title you chose here is complete garbage.

Comment: You're getting NaNs because you're doing math with DOMElements instead of their values. var fs = document.getElementById('Fahrtstrecke'); sets fs to a DOMElement, not the value of the input field with that ID.

Answer (score 0):

## if have found the answer

```
window.onload = function () {

    // CO2 Verbrauch = ((fs / ksv) * ta) / am)+(fs*0.14)
    let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    let ausgabe = document.getElementById('ergebnis'); // Result

    let ta = document.getElementById('treibstoffart'); // Selector

    let ksv = document.getElementById('Kraftstoffverbrauch'); // Inputfield
    let fs = document.getElementById('Fahrtstrecke'); // Inputfield
    let am = document.getElementById('Anzahl der Mitfahrer'); // Inputfield

    btn.onclick = function () { // Initiate Calulation
        ausgabe.innerText = (((fs.value * 1 / ksv.value * 1) * ta.value) / am.value * 1) + (fs.value * 0.14);
    };

} // End of function (window.onload)
```